# Conditional formatting for duplicates except for first value in a repeating column in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, worksheet-function

I have a a column of data with a range of dates that repeats. I'd like to apply conditional formatting to the duplicated dates, except for the first date, but in such a way that when the range of dates repeats, this formatting continues to highlight in the same manner.  Assuming the data below starts in cell A2, I'm using COUNTIF($A$2:$A2, $A2)>1.  As of now, once "Sunday, November 12, 2017" repeats towards the bottom of the column, all of the values are subject to the conditional format of red fill.

[image]

Comment: are you allowed to use a helper column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

The CF formula is

```
=AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)>1,A2=A1)
```

See how 12-Nov comes around a second time and the first line of the second batch is not red.

Comment: damn your typing faster than me :-(